# Frank opening his pants each time he sits down?

Tags: plot-explanation, everybody-loves-raymond

In the **[Everybody Loves Raymond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everybody_Loves_Raymond)** series, why does Frank (the Grandfather) always opens the zip of his pants when he sits down in chair?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

People sometimes undo their pants when the are bloated after a meal. The ever-uncouth Frank does this routinely, in front of others, reminding us that he really doesn't care what anyone thinks about him. This was a running gag that appears to have been originated by the creators of the show.

In a book about the creation of the series, *You're Lucky You're Funny: How Life Becomes a Sitcom*, Phil Rosenthal writes about the casting of Frank Barone. They were looking for a "nonethnic ethnic" to contrast with the more ethnic Italian/Jewish Ray Romano and Brad Garrett. When Peter Boyle arrived for the audition he was furious because he had had trouble finding the place.

> He scared me, and I gave him the part.
>
> He happened to be funny, too, when he calmed down. But we saw that we
>   could use a little of that anger... Lucky for us, he was also
>   hilarious at sitting in a chair with his pants open and rifling
>   one-liner at his wife, his sons, and anyone else in range. We had the
>   father.

Comment: Interesting additional trivia from the book: Boyle was once a monk, and John Lennon was the best man at his wedding.

Comment: Kind of similar to Al Bundy always putting his hand down the front waistband of his pants when he sits on the couch and picks up the TV remote.